# Phone did not appear in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone 8 development. I have registered (unlocked) my phone in Windows Phone Developer registration. And I can see the phone in File Explorer.
But when I launch MSVC 2013 Update 2 and open `DirectX 3D shooting game sample`, I can only see a plenty of emulators in dropbox and I don't see my phone.

What could be wrong?

I did not register as a Windows phone developer yet because it requires me to pay, but I hope I should be able to launch Microsoft's samples on real device without paying?

Comment: Nope. You can only install non-published apps if you are a developer account holder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you google this?

[Deploying apps to a device MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> You have to meet the following prerequisites before you can deploy an app to a Windows Phone device:
>
> - You must be a registered developer. For info about registering as a developer, [see Registration info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206719%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

It's actually bullet point number one on the documentation.