# How to debug on a phone via USB for DirectX apps projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, window, directx

I created DirectX universal apps in VS2013. I can only find emulators to debug my apps. There is no "device" to select so I failed to test my phone apps on a real phone.

How can I connect to a device? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phone did not appear in visual studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146702/phone-did-not-appear-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are building for 'ARM' when trying to build and deploy to a physical device. If you have 'Win32' or 'x86' for your build configuration you will only be able to build and deploy to the emulators.